# CUDA Compiler Object to Executable

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to get a CUDA application to compile using command line, but I'm having troubles.

I'm aware that running the command

```
nvcc -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin" -c -D_DEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler /EHsc,/W3,/nologo,/Od,/Zi,/MTd -o test.obj test.cu
```

from my batch file generates an obj file I need to use a linker with to make an executable. I was having nigh unfixable issues with Visual Studio, so I'm trying to avoid it, but I have no idea how to finish compiling my program.

What I need to know is: What should I do with my object file to get to an executable I can actually run?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @njuffa I've updated the post, it should be more clear now.

Comment: Just remove the -c option...

Comment: @talonmies That did absolutely nothing.

Comment: It solved your problem, you just don't realize it. In your example above, the output file you specified is now a fully linked executable. Trying running it from the commnd line and see for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `test.cu` is a complete application (e.g. has a `main` function, etc.), two changes to your command line could be to delete the `-c` switch and to change the `-o` switch to specify a typical windows file executable name, such as `test.exe`, i.e. `-o test.exe`.

The following test case demonstrates this on Windows 7, CUDA 8, and VS 2015:

```
C:\Users\bob\Documents>type test.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void t(){
  printf("hello\n");
}

int main(){

  t<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
  return 0;
}
C:\Users\bob\Documents>nvcc -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin" -D_DEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xc
ompiler /EHsc,/W3,/nologo,/Od,/Zi,/MTd -o test.exe test.cu
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-depreca
ted-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
test.cu
   Creating library test.lib and object test.exp

C:\Users\bob\Documents>test
hello
no error

C:\Users\bob\Documents>
```

Note that even the change to the `-o` switch is not strictly necessary.  This switch merely specifies the output file **name** and does nothing with respect to the actual compile flow (which in this case is controlled by the presence or absence of the `-c` switch -- see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-specifying-compilation-phase)).  You can prove this to yourself by leaving that `-o` switch as-is.  You will then have an executable file called `test.obj`, which you can prove to yourself by typing `test.obj` at the command prompt.  It will execute with the same output as what is shown above.

But it may be confusing,  and is not a typical file naming convention for windows.